# In complete UV GRID

Tags: modeling, animation, uv

[image]

Why is the UV GRID Not appearing on half of the model?

Comment: Did you select All in the viewport before unwrapping your object? It looks as if the teapot lid may not have been selected when you unwrapped the object.  From the two questions you've asked so far I'd suggest watching a comprehensive video on using the UV editor before you go any further. There are lots of them online.

Comment: How shall we know that from this screenshot? The upper parts lid and handle look like they have a default white material. Have you assigned the grid material to those parts? You're not even showing the material slots in your image.

Comment: I got the error. Irrespective of that, please suggest any good source to understand UV Editing

Comment: There's a comprehensive tutorial by Darrin Lile [here](https://youtu.be/GTd8NBg8EZU) which might help.

Answer (score 0):

1 your model must be whole unwraped
select all in edit mode and press U to unwrap
(remember to create proper seems on object)
2 assign all vertex to material with uv grid
create material with uv grid in material tab
select all in edit mode and assign to material

here is video with some workflow
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4mas3bNO3s

topic you can research in web that conect with un unwraping :
live unvrap, pining, packing islands, streaching uv.